# why function is return first if due to hoisting variable should be on top of the scope which is function in my case?

Tags: javascript

dude to hositing variable should be on top of the scope this so that variable on the displayInstructor function should be on top of the scope but it still return undefined why ? should not answer should be the variable value ? because dude to hoisting it should be on top

```
function displayInstructor(){
    return instructor;
    var instructor = "Loser";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) - `It's important to point out that the hoisting will affect the variable declaration, but not its value's initialization. The value will be indeed assigned when the assignment statement is reached`.

The variable `instructor` will be hoisted at the top of function `displayInstructor`, however it's value will be assigned upon reaching the statement `var instructor = "Loser";`. The `return` statement is used before the actual assignment code is executed and at that time the variable `instructor` is `undefined`.

```js
function displayInstructor(){
    console.log(instructor) // undefined
    return instructor;
    var instructor = "Loser";
}

console.log(displayInstructor());
```

Instead first assign the value and then return the variable.

```js
function displayInstructor() {
  var instructor = "Loser";
  return instructor;
}

console.log(displayInstructor());
```

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter first goes through the code, creates variables and assigns them to undefined. This function will return undefined because the return will work before the assignment.

Comment: well i thought hositing mean that variable automatically gones on top which mean that variable should get the value and then other return or other stuff happened